# How to add new column to Pandas dataframe with log value

Tags: python

i have the followig pandas df ,

```
   Price  Generic
0     3.5     3
1       2     4
3     3.4    23
```

i want create the new column with log value:

```
import numpy as np
df["log Price"]=np.log(df["Price"])
```

but does not work, the error is:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'float'
```

I tried converting the type to float, with :

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].float()

**AttributeError**: 'Series' object has no attribute 'float'
```

thanks!!!

Comment: The error is clear. You can't call `float()`. `.astype(float)`

Comment: can you do print(type(df)) (just to make sure you are actually working with a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The conversion should be done like this:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype('float64')
```

Comment: gives me the following error:float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'type'